# TexStudio color profile matching TeX StackExchange code samples?

Tags: texstudio, editors, color-profile

Does anybody know if this exists, and if it does, where I could find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole Stack Exchange network uses [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) for syntax highlighting. Reading its [`TeX` lexer](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-tex.js), and maybe some [discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/872/text-immediate-following-double-backslashes-is-highlighted-as-macro-inside-a-cod), you can figure out there are just a few regular expressions doing the matching. Crossing the data with the [default stylesheet](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/prettify.css) you can see only six classes are needed. To get their attributes you can either perform the exegesis of the [minified stylesheet](http://cdn.sstatic.net/tex/all.css) of this site or use your browser's inspector. The result (shomewhat interpreted):

```css
.prettyprint { background-color: #eeeeee; } /* code snippet */
.pln { color: #000000; }  /* plain text and whitespace */
.com { color: #868686; }  /* comments */
.kwd { color: #8a4a0b; }  /* macros ([a-Z@]* or single char) */
.typ { color: #2b91af; }  /* $ & */
.lit { color: #953838; }  /* dimensions */
.pun { color: #145680; }  /* {}[]()= */
```

You now need to put this into a TeXstudio color profile. This can be done with relative ease (`Options > Configure TeXstudio > Syntax Highlighting`). The match won't be perfect, since the highlighting routines are quite different: TeXstudio *wants* to be smarter. Here is something to get you started:

```
[formats]
data\align-ampersand\bold=false
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#2b91af
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\wrapAround=false
data\background\background=#eeeeee
data\background\bold=false
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\wrapAround=false
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\foreground=#868686
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\wrapAround=false
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\foreground=#868686
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\wrapAround=false
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\foreground=#000000
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\wrapAround=false
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\wrapAround=false
data\extra-keyword\bold=false
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#8a4a0b
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\wrapAround=false
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\foreground=#8a4a0b
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\wrapAround=false
data\link\bold=false
data\link\fontFamily=
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\pointSize=0
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\underline=false
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\link\wrapAround=false
data\magicComment\bold=false
data\magicComment\fontFamily=
data\magicComment\foreground=#868686
data\magicComment\italic=false
data\magicComment\overline=false
data\magicComment\pointSize=0
data\magicComment\priority=-1
data\magicComment\strikeout=false
data\magicComment\underline=false
data\magicComment\waveUnderline=false
data\magicComment\wrapAround=false
data\math-delimiter\bold=false
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#2b91af
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\wrapAround=false
data\math-keyword\bold=false
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\foreground=#8a4a0b
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\wrapAround=false
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\foreground=#000000
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\wrapAround=false
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\wrapAround=false
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\wrapAround=false
data\preedit\bold=false
data\preedit\fontFamily=
data\preedit\italic=false
data\preedit\overline=false
data\preedit\pointSize=0
data\preedit\priority=-1
data\preedit\strikeout=false
data\preedit\underline=false
data\preedit\waveUnderline=false
data\preedit\wrapAround=false
data\structure\bold=false
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\wrapAround=false
data\text\bold=false
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\wrapAround=false
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\wrapAround=false
version=1.0
```

Load it with `Options > Load Profile`. Have fun.